# Ning like open source alternatives

Tags: php, open-source, social-networking

I have to make something like Ning ( a website where users can create their own sites/networks) .

Another example would be webs.com

Are there any Open Source alternatives (PHP only) to these ?

Comment: Are you just looking for software, which you would need to host yourself; or for full platform like Ning provides (runs it) but just free and running on Open Source?

Answer (score 2):

Wall from Indian Srinivas Tamada it's not full open source, you must pay to buy the script, but after you buy you have the script and database, all open. If you want study, maybe it's a good way, but have some bugs, I bought one.

http://wall.9lessons.info/

Answer (score 0):

Try GROU.PS - http://grou.ps